# What does 'be made for the eyes alone' mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The following is from 'The Tiger: A True Story of Vengeance and Survival' by John Vaillant

> The taiga was at its winter finest and seemed **made for the eyes
>   alone**: the sunshine was so brilliant, the snow so pristine, the sky
>   so depthless, the stillness of the forest so profound that speech or
>   motion of any kind felt like an intrusion.

What does 'be made for the eyes alone' mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its silence and stillness it was like an image, a simple vision, a purely visual experience.

"speech or motion of any kind felt like an intrusion"

Even the sensory and mental apparatus required to process movement seemed as though it did not belong there because "the stillness of the forest [was] so profound".

The author might have written "for the eye alone", in the singular, especially since he talks about depthlessness.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official reference to what I'm suggesting, but IMO,

> **made for the eyes alone**

Something that looks very beautiful, a view that will please the viewer.

The '*taiga*', which I believe is a snow forest, must be a very picturesque location, and to see something that beautiful may give the viewer a feeling of joy and amazement, and can make him think that this was made only for him, so that he could just sit and watch this place till time ends.